# CGI renders to screen shell script output

Tags: c++, linux, cgi, mongoose-web-server

I created a CGI in C++. This program calls a shell script `script.sh` this way

```
system("script.sh")
```

I don't know why but when I use the CGI the web page displays all the output of the script.
What can I do to avoid that? I inserted an `echo off` but it doesn't work and I still see all the output. Is there a way to disable that? I am using LINUX Red Hat 6.2 and uses `Mongoose` as web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, it's good to use something like `system("script.sh >> log.txt 2>&1")` to capture all normal and error output and redirect it into `log.txt`.  Otherwise this output is directed to `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, and `STDOUT` is the output of your CGI to the HTTP stream.

Having this in place, it may also improve your script to have an input that enables or disables this logging, something like `&logging=1` amongst the CGI parameters and then you would have something like the following to control the output:

```
if (logging==1) {
  system("script.sh >> log.txt 2>&1");
}
else {
  system("script.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1");
}
```

Comment: Hi Abiessu. Thanks a lot, it works very well and solved my issue (plus I have also log).

Comment: You're welcome, also make note of my update in case your log file starts getting too big.